# Reuse of alias in a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, alias, reusability

Use alias as an another column. For example, take the below query.

`SELECT 'Santosh' as fname, 'Jadi' as lname, fname;`

I want to re-use alias `fname` as a third column.

Is it possible? If yes, how can i achieve it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Have `'Santosh'` output as both the first and third column in your result set?

Comment: Reuse means what? Yes, you can, but you still need a valid clause to get data - field, constant, function, just something. Just adding ", name" does not provide data.

Comment: if fname is column in db table, then you can, but what for?

Comment: @Diado Yes, exactly.

Comment: @PawelCz want to fetch it by alias name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access to `fname`, you need to put your query inside a sub-query as below:

```
SELECT K.fname, K.lname, K.fname as NewFname 
FROM(    
      SELECT 'Santosh' as fname, 'Jadi' as lname
) as K
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do :

```
select t.fname, t.lname, t.fname as thirdcolumn
from ( values ('Santosh', 'Jadi') 
     ) t (fname, lname);
```

For your actual table you can re-express it as :

```
select t.*, tt.fname as thirdcolumn
from table t cross apply 
     ( values (col) 
     ) tt (fname);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use CTE and it will give you free hand, You may use them multiple times without any extra work.

```
WITH MyTable AS
(
  SELECT 'Santosh' as fname, 'Jadi' as lname
)
SELECT fname, lname, fname
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

yes this is possible example below

```
SELECT  weekdayname as A,weekdayname as A from
(
SELECT 'Sunday' AS weekdayname UNION ALL
SELECT 'Monday' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tuesday' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Wednesday' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Thursday' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Friday' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Saturday'

) T
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `subquery` in such case

```
SELECT fname, lname, 
    fname AS col3,
    fname AS col4 -- so on
FROM (SELECT 'Santosh' as fname, 'Jadi' as lname) t
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
fname   lname   col3    col4
Santosh Jadi    Santosh Santosh
```